# Python: recursive way to subtract from class attributes?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a class with many attributes, and when I give a number, I would like it to subtract that from one attribute, but if the amount is greater than the attribute subtracted from, move to the next attribute with what is left over. Example:

```
def subt(self, amount):
    self.attr1 += amount
    if self.attr1 < 0:
        self.attr2 += self.attr1
        self.attr1 = 0
        if self.attr2 < 0:
            # etc...
```

It feel like there should be a concise recursive way to accomplish the same thing, but I don't know how with the all the different attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the attributes using `.__dict__` You need a list for the order you want to subtract. Something like this works.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 100
        self.bar = 200
        self.baz = 300
        self.sub_stack = ['foo', 'baz', 'bar']

    def subt(self, amount):
        tmp_stack = self.sub_stack[:]
        while tmp_stack and amount:
            key = tmp_stack.pop(0)
            val = self.__dict__[key]
            if val > amount:
                self.__dict__[key] -= amount
                amount = 0
            else:
                amount -= self.__dict__[key]
                self.__dict__[key]=0
        return amount
```

return value is the remainder on amount after iterating through your attributes

Comment: I had thought about that. I always feel strange editing the `__dict__` attr, but it seems like that will make the most sense in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Does making a list out of all the attributes work?

```
def subt(self, amount): 
    i = 0
    while i<self.attrlist.len:
        if attrlist[i] < amount:
            attrlist[i] -= amount
            break
```

Comment: not really. The attributes all have specific names for reasons beyond this little part.

Comment: That's not going to do what he wants... its just going to subtract the original value from each item that is less than the amount. He wants a carryover subtraction.

Comment: This is does indicate you don't know much Python, do you? ".len"? One thing I like doing is testing my answers vbefore posting them -this avoids incorrect answers, and I lear a lot with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way is to create a list of all your attributes - do it either manually, 
or, if your attribute names follow a pattern (like the attrN series on the example),
you can automate the creation of such a list.

```
def subt(self, amount):
    #all_attrs = ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"]
    # or this step can be automated by something like:
    all_attrs = sorted(attr_name for attr_name in self.__class__.__dict__.keys() if attr_name.startswith("attr"))
    for i, attr_name in all_attrs:
        self.__setattr__(getattr(self, attr_name) + amount)
        if gettattr(self, attr_name) < 0:
            amount = gettattr(self, attr_name)
            self.__setattr__(self, attr_name, 0)
        else: 
            break
```